# Is it UB to reinterpret_cast a T* to a uintptr_t, reinterpret_cast that uintptr_t to a void*, then static_cast that void* back to a T*?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-address, reinterpret-cast, static-cast

I am writing a C++ tagged pointer. I have a question about whether the operations I use to implement its basic functionality cause undefined behavior:

- When constructing a tagged pointer given a pointer `T*`, I `reinterpret_cast` the pointer to a `uintptr_t`. This allows me to perform bitwise operations on the memory address, which are necessary to add/extract/inspect the tag.
- When the user requests the original pointer back, I use `reinterpret_cast` to cast the `uintptr_t` to a `void*` (after removing the tag). If a pointer to a specific type is needed, I take that `void*` and `static_cast`  it to `T*` (assuming `T` is indeed the type held within the tagged pointer).

So, in summary, I am performing the following transformations on a `T*`:

- `reinterpret_cast`ing the `T*` to a `uintptr_t`
- Later, `reinterpret_cast`ing that `uintptr_t` to a `void*`, and possibly `static_cast`ing that `void*` back to a `T*`.

Does any of this result in undefined behavior? Additionally, am I using `reinterpret_cast` and `static_cast` correctly, in their intended use cases?

Comment: I think the casts you describe above are all okay (although I'm not a language lawyer so I'm not going to commit to an Answer saying so); the tricky part is knowing which bitwise operations are allowable on the `uintptr_t` without potentially corrupting the pointer.  AFAIK if you want to be 100% portable you can't modify the `uintptr_t` value at all, because any bit you modify might be used in some architecture somewhere for something other purpose.  If you know what architectures you are targetting, OTOH you can determine what bits they aren't (currently) using and re-use those for your tag.

Comment: reinterpret casting to and from `void*` should be safe, tha technique is used in type-erasure scenarios. Also as long as you keep the `void*` internal to your template class you will know for sure it points to a "T". The real problem you miuhgt have is that your tagged pointer will overlap with addressable memory (e.g. bits used for tag are also needed to address all memory). So if you can spare the memory : why not make a struct of both T* and a tag field?

Comment: Like @JeremyFriesner I am not a language-laywer either. And I agree your solution would probably be platform specific in its correctness because you probably are making assumptions on what addresses are addressable, the size of your pointer (size of your memory addresses).

Comment: FWIW in my tagged-pointer implementation I use the least significant bit(s) (how many I can use depends on the alignment of the type, of course), and in a pinch the most significant bits, although things like Android's MTE ( https://source.android.com/docs/security/test/memory-safety/arm-mte ) make the upper bits verboten too, so I have a compile-time fallback to just storing the bits as a separate uintptr_t field instead)

Comment: reinterpret_cast between uintptr_t and pointers is not safe. Use static_cast instead.

Comment: @PepijnKramer No, void* doesn't have to be of the same size as other pointers.

Comment: I think you have to go `T*` <-> `void*` <-> `uintptr_t`, or cut out the middle man and go `T*` <-> `uintptr_t`. There is no requirement that the bit pattern for `T*` pointers have the same format as `void*` pointers. (And they won't be, on systems that are not byte-addressible.) Of course, this is all moot because you are going to do arithmetic on the `uintptr_t` which is a hard dependency on implementation-specific behavior anyway.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Good to know. I usually stay away from casting pointers as much as I can. So I never ran into this.

Comment: Correction. You might not be able to go `T*` <-> `uintptr_t`. `uintptr_t` is guaranteed to be able to hold a `void*` but perhaps not necessarily a `T*`.

Comment: @RaymondChen it doesn't seem like OP needs `T*` to have same representation as `void*`. He just needs a guaranteed round trip between `T*` and `uintptr_t` where `T*` <-> `void*` <-> `uintptr_t` is a viable solution. I guess it's part of a smart pointer lib, trying to piggy pack some metadata using `uintptr_t` as stored pointer. If either `::new`, `malloc` or `std::allocator` is used, `alignof(max_align_t)` gives the upper bound on amount of data that can be stored in the low order bits. A costume allocator can provide better guarantees, though.

Comment: @Red.Wave The C++ standard defers `uintptr_t` to the C standard, and the C standard says " The following type designates an unsigned integer type, other than a bit-precise integer type, with the property that any valid pointer to void can be converted to this type, then converted back to pointer to void, and the result will compare equal to the original pointer". So only interconversion with `void*` is guaranteed. It may not work for `T*`.

Comment: @RaymondChen but `void*` and `T*` are interconvertible (so long as `T*` is not function or member pointer). So, using `void*` as the middleman on both conversions must result in valid code. The problem I see is that OP doesn't use `void*` in the first conversion.

Comment: @Red.Wave Right. You have to use `void*` as the middle man. You can't go from `T*` directly to `uintptr_t`. As I noted, the issue is moot because OP intends to do implementation-dependent things to the `uintptr_t`, so portability is already a lost cause. Maybe the idea is to *minimize* the amount of nonportable code? Because pointer tagging is itself nonportable. (Or maybe it's "I'm okay with being nonportable, as long as there's no UB.")

Comment: @RaymondChen There's not enough data on intended usage to make aguess about portability. If the allocator class/function is guaranteed to leave some invariant number of bits, that might be portable (e.g. `auto alloc_fn=bind_front(aligned_alloc, 1<<N);` guarantees `N` bits for tag data). However `free` cannot be portabaly used with `aligned_alloc`.

Comment: @Red.Wave "Any pointer type may be converted to an integer type. Except as previously specified, the result is implementation-defined." So there is no requirement that the result of a cast from `void*` to `uintptr_t` is the machine address, and in fact there are systems where that is not the case, such as the PDP-10, where [a pointer to a byte](http://pdp10.nocrew.org/docs/instruction-set/Byte.html) is a combination of a word address and bit offset. Now, this is an exotic architecture by modern standards, but C++ still supports it.